# Js check login from exterior website

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i've to create a "like" button as Facebook.
So this button will be on many web sites, that calls a javascript file hosted by me, which handle hover/click/etc.. action of button.

Now, how can I check if the user is logged or not in my website (Php with sessions) with js?
So if the user is logged the like button would change text and shows that user liked it, otherwise the user will be redirected(maybe a popup) on registration page.

How can I handle this type of cross-domain(js/ajax) request?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but you could try writing an ajax call towards a php file that returns the value of the session if it exists. Then use js to check if a value was returned or not and do your magic from there.

Comment: set a cookie on their computer once they've logged in

Answer (score 0):

To enable cross-domain requests, add

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *")
```

to the top of your PHP file.

Then do something like this :

```
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']){
    echo "TRUE";
  }
  else{
    echo "FALSE";
  }
```

and take action on your page based on the value returned.